# How to highlight the currently selected column using Ember?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, ember.js

Ember comes with built-in support for sorting arrays in controllers, which makes it very convenient to update a template when the data's sort order changes.

My question, however, is how to conveniently (1) highlight the currently selected column the data is sorted by and (2) the sort order (ascending or descending). By highlighting, I mean adding an up or down arrow, or something similar.

At the moment, I am fiddling with this in the view layer using jQuery, but I feel there must be an easier solution given the elegance with which Ember handles trivial problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

For table I would recommend to use [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/). It’s a powerful library and you can use with ember without concern about anything

In my case I've a function where I passed the id of the table, the header and the data that it’s a multidimensional array.

```
function setDataTable(tableId,header,data,elementToOrder,typeOrder,index,value,displayLength,paginate,applyClass,callback){
    if(tableId==null||header==null||data==null)
        return;
    var table=$('#'+tableId);
    var tableElement=document.getElementById(tableId);
    if(tableElement==null)
        return;
    if($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(tableElement))
        table.dataTable().fnDestroy();
    if(elementToOrder==null)
        elementToOrder=0;
    if(typeOrder==null)
        typeOrder="desc";
    if(displayLength===null)
        displayLength="10";
    if(paginate==null)
        paginate=true;
    table.dataTable({
        "sDom":"<'row no-side-margin'<'float-left'l><'float-rigth'f>r>t<'row no-side-margin'<'float-left'i><'float-rigth'p>>",
        "sPaginationType":"bootstrap",
        "oLanguage":{
            "sLengthMenu":"_MENU_ Itens por pagina",
            "sSearch":"Pesquisar:",
            "sInfo":"Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ linhas",
            "sInfoEmpty":"Não existem linhas para mostrar",
            "sEmptyTable":"Não há dados disponíveis na tabela",
            "oPaginate":{
                "sNext":"Próximo",
                "sPrevious":"Anterior"
            }
        },
        "fnDrawCallback":function(oSettings){
            if(callback==null)
                return;
            window.setTimeout(callback,100);
        },
        "iDisplayLength":displayLength,
        "aaSorting":[[elementToOrder,typeOrder]],
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bDeferRender":true,
        "bPaginate":paginate,
        "aaData":data,
        "aoColumns":header,
        "fnRowCallback":function(nRow,aData,iDisplayIndex,iDisplayIndexFull){
            if(index==null)
                return;
            if(!applyClass) 
                return;
            if(aData[index]===value)
                $(nRow).addClass("danger");else
                $(nRow).addClass("success");
        }
    });
    table.removeAttr('style');
}
```

For instance, imagine that you have a table in you HTML like this:

```
<table id="phoneItemsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed"></table>
```

Them I have a header like this:

```
var PhoneHeader = [ {
    "sTitle": "State"
},{
    "sTitle": "# Phone"
},{
    "sTitle": "# Client"
}];
```

and finally a multidimensional array like:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.pushObject(["ok", "4455522", "221334"]);
myArray.pushObject(["not ok", "4455522", "221334"]);
```

Them I would call my function:

```
setDataTable("phoneItemsTable", PhoneHeader, myArray );
```

The others parameter are for customization of the table.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: i have the same issue. How can i add column based client side sorting to a table? the table is created using BS3 and i am wondering if i could datatables with it.