# ember.js works very slowly with big data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, event-loop

I need to display table with 1000 rows. But when I pass content to the controller, page does not respond within a few seconds

Below is the code I wrote to show the problem

You can see work demo at http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qixoruyi/8/edit

When i click "change content" button, page does not respond within a few seconds, at this time, the counter is not increased, then ember at this time does not return control to javascript event loop.
1000 rows is too much for ember? Or am I doing something wrong?

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div>counter: {{counter}}</div>

<button {{action "changeContent"}}>change content</button>

<table border="1">
<tbody>
{{#each}}
  <tr>
    {{#each}}
      <td>{{this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

```js
var newContent = [];
var i,j, t, x=0;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  t = [];
  for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
    t.push("x"+x++);
  }
  newContent.push(t);
}

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [];
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  counter: 0,
  init: function() {
    var t = this, c = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
      t.set('counter', c++)
    }, 200);
  },
  actions: {
    changeContent: function() {
      this.set('content', newContent);
    }
  },
});
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: As an aside, is that not a bit tricky for users to deal with? Would infinite scroll using something like ember-cloak [1](http://eviltrout.com/2014/01/04/hiding-offscreen-ember.html) [2](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking) be a better alternative?

Comment: For rendering big tables in Ember I usually end up with [ember-table](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table). It handles performance issues and stuff like lazy loading in a very nice manner.

Comment: The Emberjs story for "displaying lists of things" is pretty inferior currently. Honestly I'm not sure how they take themselves seriously with this problem left unaddressed. Note that 1000 rows isn't "Big Data" by any stretch. And in fact severe performance issues with Emberjs can be encountered with as little as 100 rows. It is possible that the "Ember Cloaking" project might help you, and apparently they are refactoring the terribly non-performant template rendering system with an upcoming re-write but there has not been any update on that for months now.

Answer (score 0):

I Know what you mean and I've already had this problem, so try to check my solution that I had posted in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857337/how-to-highlight-the-currently-selected-column-using-ember/21857878#21857878)